# How to properly mock an object using the socket module in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, sockets, mocking, python-unittest

I am currently trying to find the best way of mocking the `socket` module without having to patch each of its methods like `connect`, `send`, `recv` (which works but pollutes the test function with many `patch`es).

Currently I have an object that handles connection via the `socket` module:

`socket_handler.py`

```py
import socket


class MySocketHandler:
    def __init__(self):
        self.host_ip = "127.0.0.1"
        self.server_port = 9999
        self.tcp_client = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

    def send_hello(self):
        data = "hello!"
        try:
            # Establish connection to TCP server and exchange data
            self.tcp_client.connect((self.host_ip, self.server_port))
            self.tcp_client.sendall(data.encode())

            # Read data from the TCP server and close the connection
            received = self.tcp_client.recv(1024)
        finally:
            self.tcp_client.close()
```

and my test file `socket_handler_test.py`:

```py
import unittest
from unittest.mock import MagicMock, patch
from socket_handler import MySocketHandler


class SocketHandlerTest(unittest.TestCase):
    @patch("socket_handler.socket.socket")
    def test_send_hello(self, socket_mock):
        socket_mock.recv = MagicMock()
        socket_mock.connect = MagicMock()
        socket_mock.sendall = MagicMock()

        socket_handler = MySocketHandler()
        socket_handler.send_hello()

        self.assertEqual(socket_mock.tcp_client.connect.call_count, 1)
        self.assertEqual(socket_mock.tcp_client.connect.call_args[0][0][0], "127.0.0.1")
        self.assertEqual(socket_mock.tcp_client.connect.call_args[0][0][1], 9999)
        self.assertEqual(socket_mock.tcp_client.recv.call_count, 1)
        self.assertEqual(
            socket_mock.tcp_client.sendall.call_args[0][0],
            bytes("hello", encoding="utf-8"),
        )
```

But when running `python3 -m unittest socket_handler_test.py` I get a:

```sh
    self.assertEqual(socket_mock.tcp_client.connect.call_count, 1)
AssertionError: 0 != 1
```

I tried digging a little bit with various ways of Mocking the functions but have not been successful yet. Is it even possible or do I have to stick with mocking each particular function of the `socket` library?

Comment: `socket_mock.tcp_client` - what value do you expect that to have? It's `socket_handler` that's the `MySocketHandler` instance with that attribute. You also don't need to individually set each method on the mock that `patch` creates, by default it's a `MagicMock` all of whose attributes are also `MagicMock`s.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to [jonrsharpe](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3001761/jonrsharpe)'s comment I fixed the code and indeed I misunderstood what object was patched already.

Here's the working solution:

```py
import unittest
from unittest.mock import MagicMock, patch
from socket_handler import MySocketHandler


class SocketHandlerTest(unittest.TestCase):
    @patch("socket_handler.socket.socket")
    def test_send_hello(self, socket_mock):
        socket_mock = MagicMock()

        socket_handler = MySocketHandler()
        socket_handler.send_hello()

        self.assertEqual(socket_handler.tcp_client.connect.call_count, 1)
        self.assertEqual(
            socket_handler.tcp_client.connect.call_args[0][0][0], "127.0.0.1"
        )
        self.assertEqual(socket_handler.tcp_client.connect.call_args[0][0][1], 9999)
        self.assertEqual(socket_handler.tcp_client.recv.call_count, 1)
        self.assertEqual(
            socket_handler.tcp_client.sendall.call_args[0][0],
            bytes("hello!", encoding="utf-8"),
        )
```